# Change TCPDF header string floating

Tags: php, tcpdf

Hello stackoverflow people, i need help with TCPDF, i dont know how to make header string float right. Bellow there is a code of my script. I want to leave header logo where it is, but that header string is problem. SO how could i change it to right?

```
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, $AppUI->_('Project Completed Task Report'), PDF_HEADER_STRING);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create custome header , you need to extend TCPDF class and override `Header()` function :
Then in the function there is a `Cell()` method that you need to modify one of its attributes:

Assuming

```
 $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< Header TITLE >>', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
```

the `'C'` indicates CENTER (by default ), you need to change to `'R'` to achive float-right

```
  $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< Header TITLE >>', 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
```

Here's the example I simplified :  (change the `require_once()` value according to where your TCPDF folder belongs)

```
<?php
require_once('D:\tcpdf\tcpdf.php');

// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo_example.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
        // Title to right allignment
        $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< Header TITLE >>', 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
    }
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 003');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);



// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

   // ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 12);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// set some text to print
$txt = <<<EOD
Custom page header and footer are defined by extending the TCPDF class and overriding the Header() and Footer() methods.
EOD;

// print a block of text using Write()
$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

To get more information go to http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php